# How to remove pygame button image from screen?

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm using pygame and I know that you can't remove an image once you blit it to the screen and have to draw the background over it again. In my case Im trying to clear button objects from the screen. Yet even when I fill the screen, I can still click on the buttons even though they are no longer visible. Is there a way to stop the buttons from working?

Answer (score 0):

When you draw something in Pygame, it is drawn on [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object, associated with the display. You cannot "delete" something" what is draw on a Surface. A Surface contains just a bunch pixel organized in rows and columns. If you want to "delete" an images, then you must not draw it.
In general the entire scene is redrawn in every frame of the application loop. The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit frames per second to limit CPU usage